# Does python's multiprocessing.Pool().map_async have an output limit?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am doing some multiprocessing with a couple dozen cores, and am using:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
# worker does some groupby operations and returns a dict of summary statistics
# huge_dataframe is a pandas.DataFrame(), 30 cols (mixed dtypes) x 1B rows
results = pool.map_async(worker, ((huge_dataframe, i) for i in xrange(3000)))
my_data = results.get()
```

However, my job never completes. It ramps up quickly enough, peaks with about as many processes running as cores I have, then slowly winds down halfway through the job until it no longer spawns new processes. I have tried editing the chunksize for map_async, the maxtasksperchild for Pool(), randomizing my (real) input list to avoid skew, but nothing seems to work. I am wondering if there is an underlying Queue used by multiprocessing.Pool() that fills up and needs to be emptied, so the program hangs indefinitely? If so, can I avoid this bottleneck with apply_async? Does that set up separate Queue objects for each process? Thanks.

Comment: Does `1B rows` == 1 *billion* rows? Because you're definitely going to run out of memory trying to feed a iterable that large into `map_async`. `map_async` converts the iterable you pass to it into a `list` prior to sending any data off to a worker, so that conversion is probably never even completing. You see as many processes as CPUs spawn because the call to `multiprocessing.Pool` does that by default as soon as you instantiate it. It uses the same `num_cpu` processes to handle every work item you give it.

Comment: I actually switched to multiprocess.Process & multiprocess.semaphore, and that worked. It actually wasn't a memory issue (I have 144gb). Something in the logic for multiprocessing.Pool was causing it not to spawn jobs about halfway through, and I never figured it out. Also, it seems as though map_async actually only runs a certain number of jobs at once (default: num_cpu), so it only pulls from a generator, for example, the number of chunks in the iterable that it can run at any given time. It also reuses the processes, just passing new data to the same PIDs to save on overhead costs.

Comment: You are correct that a `Pool` never runs more than `num_cpu` jobs concurrently by default, and that the same processes are used the whole time (unless you specify `maxtasksperchild`), However, `map_async` does consume the entire generator before it starts any jobs; it has logic in it to break the iterable it receives into chunks, and send those chunks to each worker. Literally the first thing `map_async` does is this: `if not hasattr(iterable, "__len__"): iterable = list(iterable)`. If you want to avoid that behavior, you have to use `imap` instead.